# Visual Studio Xamarin signing packages archive failed could not read as zip

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have successfully created an Android Archive using Visual Studio 2015 however whenever I try to Distribute this Archive I get this listed in the Errors section

> Signing Packages Failed
>
> Could not read XXX.apk as a zip

I've tried clearing out my App Data, Running Visual Studio as an Administrator, repairing the Xamarin installation and restarting my computer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you attach your logs from `Help -> Xamarin -> Zip Logs(last 7 days)`?  I would suspect that the name of this `.apk` might confuse the signing step.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how I fixed it but it is working now. I do think it was a problem with the project itself.